# Push notification image is read as null from the react native screen but in fact it is not null via postman

Tags: php, react-native

Thanks everyone for taking the time to try and help.
I have an app which i built in react native expo. Everything working fine except one small bug. I have push notification using expo for the app and i run a cron job script in plain php to send data to the app and read the push notification. When I click on it opens great except the image received in data is null. But when i run my script which is on the online shared hosting using postman, the link to the image is read right and the image opens in the app and in the console the image value is not null but it is a link. I can't seem to tell what might be the issue here because the image is read right when i run the script manually or by postman but when the cron run the script the image value is null.

I have my doubts that the section below is the issue, because from my experience you can't include files in a cron job script, you have to put everything in the same file, and because i am using document root to get check if the file exist

```
    $image_link_check = $documentRoot . "/admin/uploads/news/" .$latest_news['image'];

    if(file_exists($image_link_check)) {

        $image = $imageBaseUrl . "/news/" . $latest_news['image'];

    } else {

        $image = NULL;

    }
```

here is my page where the data is received it is called NewsDetailsScreen.js

```
    import {
    StyleSheet,
    SafeAreaView,
    Image,
    Button,
    View,
    Platform,
    StatusBar,
    ScrollView,
    TouchableOpacity,
    Text,
} from 'react-native';
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from 'react';
import AppText from '../components/AppText';
import colors from '../config/colors';
import { openBrowserAsync } from 'expo-web-browser';
import { CommonActions, useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

import { useFocusEffect } from '@react-navigation/native';

import themeContext from '../theme/themeContext';

export default function NewsDetailsScreen({ route }) {
    const news = route.params;
    const navigation = useNavigation();

    const theme = useContext(themeContext);
    const [author, setAuthor] = useState();
    const [darkModeOn, setDarkModeOn] = useState(false);

    const retrieveDarkMode = async () => {
        try {
            const jsonValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem('darkModeOn');

            if (jsonValue !== null) {
                const parsedValue = JSON.parse(jsonValue);
                setDarkModeOn(parsedValue);
            }
        } catch (e) {
            // error reading value
            console.log('error: ', e);
        }
    };

    const displayAuthor = (author) => {
        if (
            author !== 'Editor' &&
            author !== 'F1 Desk' &&
            author !== 'Motorsport Network' &&
            author !== 'RACER Staff' &&
            author !== 'GPblog' &&
            author !== ''
        ) {
            setAuthor('By ' + author);
        } else {
            setAuthor('');
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        displayAuthor(news.author);
        console.log(
            'news: ------------------------------------------------------------------ ',
            news.image
        );
        //navigation.navigate('Root', { screenName: 'NewsDetailsScreen' });
    });

    useFocusEffect(
        React.useCallback(() => {
            retrieveDarkMode();

            return () => {};
        }, [])
    );

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        author: {
            color: colors.lightBlue,
            marginTop: 10,
        },
        button: {
            marginTop: 20,
            marginBottom: 20,
        },
        date: {
            marginTop: 10,
            fontSize: 15,
            color: darkModeOn ? colors.white : colors.lightBlack,
        },
        description: {
            marginTop: 10,
            color: darkModeOn ? colors.white : colors.lightBlack,
        },
        detailsContainer: {
            padding: 20,
        },
        image: {
            width: '100%',
            height: 330,
        },
        // scrollView: {
        //     marginTop: Platform.OS === 'android' ? StatusBar.currentHeight : 0,
        //     backgroundColor: darkModeOn ? colors.black : colors.white,
        // },
        mainContainer: {
            marginTop: Platform.OS === 'android' ? StatusBar.currentHeight : 0,
            backgroundColor: theme.backgroundColor,
        },
        source: {
            marginTop: 10,
            color: darkModeOn ? colors.white : colors.lightBlack,
        },
        title: {
            fontSize: 24,
            fontWeight: '500',
            color: darkModeOn ? colors.white : colors.lightBlack,
        },
        backText: {
            color: darkModeOn ? colors.white : colors.lightBlack,
            fontSize: 35,
            paddingLeft: 5,
            paddingBottom: 10,
            position: 'absolute',
            left: 10,
            bottom: '-15%',
        },
    });

    return (
        <ScrollView style={styles.scrollView}>
            <SafeAreaView style={styles.mainContainer}>
                <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={() => {
                        //navigation.navigate('Latest News');
                        navigation.dispatch(CommonActions.goBack());
                        // navigation.dispatch(
                        //     CommonActions.reset({
                        //         index: 0,
                        //         routes: [{ name: 'LatestNews' }],
                        //     })
                        // );
                    }}
                    style={{ width: '100%', height: 45, flexDirection: 'row' }}
                    activeOpacity={1}
                >
                    <Text style={styles.backText}>&#x2039;</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                {/* <Image style={styles.image} source={news.image} /> */}
                {news.image !== null ? (
                    <Image
                        style={styles.image}
                        source={{
                            uri: news.image,
                        }}
                    />
                ) : (
                    <Image
                        style={styles.image}
                        source={require('../assets/f1ianIcon300x300.png')}
                    />
                )}

                <SafeAreaView style={styles.detailsContainer}>
                    <AppText style={styles.title}>{news.title}</AppText>
                    <AppText style={styles.description}>
                        {news.description}
                    </AppText>
                    {news.author !== null && (
                        <AppText style={styles.author}>{author}</AppText>
                    )}
                    <AppText style={styles.date}>{news.pubDate}</AppText>
                    <AppText style={styles.source}>
                        From {news.feedName}
                    </AppText>
                    <View style={styles.button}>
                        <Button
                            title="Read Full Article"
                            onPress={() => openBrowserAsync(news.link)}
                        />
                    </View>
                </SafeAreaView>
            </SafeAreaView>
        </ScrollView>
    );
}
```

and here is my php script (can't share all of it because it contains database informations and credentials:

```
if(array_key_exists('HTTPS', $_SERVER) && $_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {
    $site_link = "https://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "" . $base_directory;
} else {
    $site_link = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "" . $base_directory;
}

$base_directory = "";

$imageBaseUrl = $site_link . "/admin/uploads";
```

$latest_news = find_the_latest_single_news_by_subject_id($f1_subject);

```
// array_push($latest_news_array, $latest_news);

$found_feed = find_feed_info_by_feed_id($latest_news['feed_id']);

while($found_devices_assoc = mysqli_fetch_assoc($found_devices)) {

    $token = $found_devices_assoc['token'];

    $title = $latest_news['title'];
    $title = str_replace("&#39;", "'", $title);
    $title = str_replace("&#34;", "'", $title);

    $source = ucwords($found_feed['feed_name']);


    $author = str_replace("&#34;", '"', $latest_news['author']);
    $author = str_replace("&#39;", "'", $author);
    $author = str_replace(".com", "", $author);
    $author = trim($author);
    if(strtolower($author) != strtolower($found_feed['feed_name'])) {
        $author = $author;
    } else {
        $author = NULL;
    }

    $description = str_replace("&#34;", '"', $latest_news['description']);
    $description = str_replace("&#39;", "'", $description);
    $description = str_replace("\n", " ", $description);

    $pubDate = date("F j, Y", $latest_news['pubDate']) . " at " . date("g:i a", $latest_news['pubDate']);
    $insertDateTime = date("F j, Y", $latest_news['insert_date']) . " at " . date("g:i a", $latest_news['insert_date']);

    $image = "";

    if($latest_news['image'] === NULL || $latest_news['image'] === "") {

        $image = NULL;

    } else {

        $image_link_check = $documentRoot . "/admin/uploads/news/" . $latest_news['image'];
        echo "image_link_check: " . $image_link_check . "<br><br>";
        if(file_exists($image_link_check)) {

            $image = $imageBaseUrl . "/news/" . $latest_news['image'];

        } else {

            $image = NULL;

        }

    }

    if($found_devices_assoc['notificationOn'] == 1) {
        $json_payload = array(
            'to' => $token,
            'sound' => 'default',
            'title' => $source,
            'body' => $title,
            "data" => [
                "screen" => "NewsDetailsScreen",
                "id" => $latest_news['id'],
                "feedName" => $source,
                "pubDate" => $pubDate,
                "title" => $title,
                "description" => $description,
                "link" => $latest_news['link'],
                "author" => $author,
                "image" => $image,
                "insertDate" => $insertDateTime
                
            ]
           
        );

        $data = json_encode($json_payload);
        var_dump($data);
        //FCM API end-point
        $url = 'https://exp.host/--/api/v2/push/send';
        //CURL request to route notification to FCM connection server (provided by Google)
        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => "https://exp.host/--/api/v2/push/send",
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                "Accept: application/json",
                "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate",
                "Content-Type: application/json",
                "cache-control: no-cache",
                "host: exp.host"
            ),
        ));

        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        $err = curl_error($ch);
        if ($response === FALSE) {
            die('Oops! FCM Send Error: ' . curl_error($ch));
        }
        curl_close($ch);
        
        if ($err) {
            echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
        } else {
            echo $response;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in these lines, they do not work when i run the script from cron job

```
if(array_key_exists('HTTPS', $_SERVER) && $_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {
    $site_link = "https://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "" . $base_directory;
} else {
    $site_link = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "" . $base_directory;
}
```

so i replace them with :

```
$site_link = "https://site-domain.com"
```

and these lines replace :

$image_link_check = $documentRoot . "/admin/uploads/news/" . $latest_news['image'];
echo "image_link_check: " . $image_link_check . "
";
if(file_exists($image_link_check)) {

```
            $image = $imageBaseUrl . "/news/" . $latest_news['image'];

        } else {

            $image = NULL;

        }
```

replace with :

```
$image_url = $imageBaseUrl . "/news/" . $latest_news['image'];

        $image_type_check = @exif_imagetype($image_url);
        if (strpos($http_response_header[0], "200")) {
            $image = $imageBaseUrl . "/news/" . $latest_news['image'];
        } else {
            $image = NULL;
        }
```

if someone please has an answer why the above code does not work when you run the script from a cron job please share it. Thank you